# Does MS access(2003) have anything comparable to Stored procedure. I want to run a complex query in MS acceess

Tags: sql, ms-access, stored-procedures, ms-office

I have a table, call it TBL. It has two columns,call them A and B. Now in the query I require one column as A and other column should be a comma seprated list of all B's which are against A in TBL. 
e.g. TBL is like this

1   Alpha

2   Beta

1   Gamma

1   Delta

Result of query should be

1   Alpha,Gamma,Delta

2   Beta

This type of thing is very easy to do with cursors in stored procedure. But I am not able to do it through MS Access, because apparently it does not support stored procedures. 
Is there a way to run stored procedure in MS access? or is there a way through SQL to run this type of query

Comment: Does VB6 have stored procedures? Does .NET have stored procedures? Access is a database application development platform. Jet is the default database engine, which is what intended to ask about. Jet lacks stored procedures (there's no server process to manage them so there couldn't possibly be).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can concatenate the records with a User Defined Function (UDF).

The code below can be pasted 'as is' into a standard module. The SQL for you example would be:

```
SELECT tbl.A, Concatenate("SELECT B  FROM tbl
        WHERE A = " & [A]) AS ConcA
FROM tbl
GROUP BY tbl.A
```

This code is by DHookom, Access MVP, and is taken from http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=4233

```
Function Concatenate(pstrSQL As String, _
        Optional pstrDelim As String = ", ") _
            As String
    'example
    'tblFamily with FamID as numeric primary key
    'tblFamMem with FamID, FirstName, DOB,...
    'return a comma separated list of FirstNames
    'for a FamID
    '    John, Mary, Susan
    'in a Query
    '(This SQL statement assumes FamID is numeric)
    '===================================
    'SELECT FamID,
    'Concatenate("SELECT FirstName FROM tblFamMem
    '     WHERE FamID =" & [FamID]) as FirstNames
    'FROM tblFamily
    '===================================
    '
    'If the FamID is a string then the SQL would be
    '===================================
    'SELECT FamID,
    'Concatenate("SELECT FirstName FROM tblFamMem
    '     WHERE FamID =""" & [FamID] & """") as FirstNames
    'FROM tblFamily
    '===================================

    '======For DAO uncomment next 4 lines=======
    '======     comment out ADO below    =======
    'Dim db As DAO.Database
    'Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    'Set db = CurrentDb
    'Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(pstrSQL)

    '======For ADO uncomment next two lines=====
    '======     comment out DAO above     ======
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open pstrSQL, CurrentProject.Connection, _
            adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
    Dim strConcat As String 'build return string
    With rs
        If Not .EOF Then
            .MoveFirst
            Do While Not .EOF
                strConcat = strConcat & _
                    .Fields(0) & pstrDelim
                .MoveNext
            Loop
        End If
        .Close
    End With
    Set rs = Nothing
    '====== uncomment next line for DAO ========
    'Set db = Nothing
    If Len(strConcat) > 0 Then
        strConcat = Left(strConcat, _
            Len(strConcat) - Len(pstrDelim))
    End If
    Concatenate = strConcat
End Function
```

Comment: You saved my daym and made my day. What an elegant solution. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can create VBA functions and use them in your access queries. That might help you.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a way that I know of to run stored procedures in an Access database.  However, Access can execute stored procedures if it is being used against a SQL backend.  If you can not split the UI to Access and data to SQL, then your best bet will probably be to code a VBA module to give you the output you need.

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish your task you will need to use code.  One solution, using more meaningful names, is as follows:

Main table with two applicable columns:

> Table Name: Widgets
>
> Field 1: ID (Long)
>
> Field 2: Color (Text 32)

Add table with two columns:

> Table Name: ColorListByWidget
>
> Field 1: ID (Long)
>
> Field 2: ColorList (Text 255)

Add the following code to a module and call as needed to update the ColorListByWidget table:

```
Public Sub GenerateColorList()

Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim Widgets As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ColorListByWidget As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ColorList As String

Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection

cn.Execute "DELETE * FROM ColorListByWidget"
cn.Execute "INSERT INTO ColorListByWidget (ID) SELECT ID FROM Widgets GROUP BY ID"

With ColorListByWidget
   .Open "ColorListByWidget", cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
   If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
      .MoveFirst
      Do Until .EOF
         Widgets.Open "SELECT Color FROM Widgets WHERE ID = " & .Fields("ID"), cn
         If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
            Widgets.MoveFirst
            ColorList = ""
            Do Until Widgets.EOF
               ColorList = ColorList & Widgets.Fields("Color").Value & ", "
               Widgets.MoveNext
            Loop
         End If
         .Fields("ColorList") = Left$(ColorList, Len(ColorList) - 2)
         .MoveNext
         Widgets.Close
      Loop
   End If
End With


End Sub
```

The ColorListByWidget Table now contains your desired information.  Be careful that the list (colors in this example) does not exceed 255 characters.

Answer (score 1):

No stored procedures, no temporary tables.

If you needed to return the query as a recordset, you could use a disconnected recordset.

Comment: Your answer seems intersting, can you explain it a bit further?

Comment: A disconnected recordset is a device used in Access usually in place of temp tables, where you make a recordset, and then cancel it's ActiveConnection.  It's complicated, but can be used where one would need a temporary table.  I'm not familiar enough to give all details, you'll need to Google it.

Comment: A disconnected recordset is an ADO feature, not an "Access" feature. ADO is not the preferred interface to Jet data -- DAO is. And you can get the same "temp table" features by using transactions and simply not committing them.

Comment: ADO is *my* preferred interface to Jet :) If you think that "temp table" equates to transactions then you too could get to like ADO because it, unlike DAO, supports *nested* transactions.

Comment: I use ADO also, though I haven't learned all the ins and outs of it.

Comment: I did not say temp tables equated to transactions but that you can get the same performance and functionality from using uncommitted DAO transactions as you can with ADO disconnected recordsets. Sure it's a bit more complex, but if you're in an all-DAO environment, it's preferable.

Comment: "using uncommitted DAO transactions as... ADO disconnected recordsets" -- Good point! Thanks for clarifying. P.S. disconnected ADO recordsets can be fbaricated from scratch and can be hierarchical therefore better as general purpose containers but I take you point about all-DAO setups.

Comment: I drank the ADO koolaid when it came out and just didn't want to use both DAO and ADO. Many Access apps may want to grow up to a SQL server frontend some day.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps instead of asking if Jet has stored procedures, you should explain what you want to accomplish and then we can explain how to do it with Jet (it's not clear if you're using Access for your application, or just using a Jet MDB as your data store).

Comment: If they are trying to do this in Access then I'd say "Use a Report". If they are trying to do this in Jet (or any other SQL) then I'd say, "Don't. Use a report."

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use a Recordset object to loop through your query in VBA, concatenating field values based on whatever criteria you need.

If you want to return the results as strings, you'll be fine. If you want to return them as a query, that will be more complicated. You might have to create a temporary table and store the results in there so you can return them as a table or query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GetString in VBA which will return the recordset separated by any value you like (e.g. comma, dash, table cells etc.) although I have to admit I've only used it in VBScript, not Visual Basic. [W3Schools has a good tutorial which will hopefully lend itself to your needs](http://www.w3schools.com/ADO/met_rs_getstring.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You can write your stored procedure as text and send it against the database with:

```
Dim sp as string
sp = "your stored procedure here" (you can load it from a text file or a memo field?)

Access.CurrentProject.AccessConnection.Execute sp
```

This supposes you are using ADODB objects (ActiveX data Objects Library is coorectly referenced in your app).

I am sure there is something similar with DAO ...

Answer (score 0):

@Remou on DHookom's Concatenate function: neither the SQL standard nor the Jet has a `CONCATENATE()` set function. Simply put, this is because it is a violation of 1NF. I'd prefer to do this on the application side rather than try to force SQL to do something it wasn't designed to do. Perhaps ACE's (Access2007) multi-valued types is a better fit: still NFNF but at least there is engine-level support. Remember, the question relates to a *stored* object: how would a user query a non-scalar column using SQL...?

@David W. Fenton on whether Jet has stored procedures: didn't you and I discuss this in the newsgroups a couple of years ago. Since version 4.0, Jet/ACE has supported the 
following syntax in ANSI-92 Query Mode:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure (param1 datatype[, param2 datatype][, ...]) AS sqlstatement;

EXECUTE procedure [param1[, param2[, ...]];
```

So Jet is creating and executing something it knows (in one mode at least) as a 'procedure' that is 'stored' in the MDB file. However, Jet/ACE SQL is pure and simple: it has no control-of-flow syntax and a `PROCEDURE` can only contain one SQL statement, so any *procedural* code is out of the question. Therefore, the answer to whether Jet has stored procedures is subjective.

Comment: I haven't the time right at the moment to look it up, but isn't the Jet 4 "procedure" not at all like the stored procedures that most server databases offer? In other words, it's something of very limited functionality that can't possibly replace the server-type objects?

Comment: Didn't I cover all your points already? e.g. I said, "...is pure and simple: it has no control-of-flow syntax and a PROCEDURE can only contain one SQL statement, so any procedural code is out of the question", yet you still want me to clarify whether it is "something of very limited functionality"?