# Access Concatenate rows into single rows: extra conditions needed

Tags: sql, ms-access, stored-procedures, ms-office

I'm working with an Access database and I need to concatenate different related rows into 1 row. I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230241/does-ms-access2003-have-anything-comparable-to-stored-procedure-i-want-to-run) and used it with great success. However I need to add extra conditions to it, it should only be done if certain other columns are equal too.
For example:

1 X Alpha

2 Y Beta

1 X Gamma

1 Z Delta

should become

1 X Alpha,Gamma

1 Z Delta

2 Y Beta

Does anyone know to do this, especially for a newbie like me?

Comment: you seem to be de-normalising? Is that your real intent?

Comment: Are these rows all in the same table, or or are you joining rows from table1 to rows in table2?

Comment: All rows are in the same table. I know it sounds weird but I need to join them in order to apply some statistics. If I don't put them into 1 row, I get different cases in my statistical program which is no good.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are using the code supplied in [Does MS access(2003) have anything comparable to Stored procedure. I want to run a complex query in MS acceess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230241/does-ms-access2003-have-anything-comparable-to-stored-procedure-i-want-to-run).

There is no reason why you should not feed in two fields as one in your sql, so an example:

```
SELECT Number & Letter,
Concatenate("SELECT Letter & Alpha As FirstField FROM tblTable
     WHERE Number & Letter =""" & [Number] & [Letter] & """") as FirstFields
FROM tblT
```

Comment: There is no Concatenate() function in Jet SQL, which is already pointed out in the answers to the cited question.

Comment: SQL (the language) does not have a concatentate function because it would violate 1NF by creating a non-scalar type. ACE (Microsoft Access Engine, introduced in Access2007 to replace Jet) has multi-values data types if you want an engine-supported way of violating 1NF ;-)

Comment: As the OP remarked, this data is for feeding in to a statistical program. This would appear to be a Access used under point 3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469799/what-are-the-appropriate-uses-for-ms-access/471798#471798