# many-to-many into summary column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got a db like this:

```
Accounts 
--------
id
BankName
AcctNumber
Balance

AccountGroups
-------------
id
GroupName

JoinAccountsGroups
------------------
aid
gid
```

I'm trying to generate data like this:

```
Bank       AcctNum       Balance    Groups
--------|--------------|----------|----------------
Citi       930938        400        Payroll
B of A     8372933       100        Monthly, Payroll
Wells      09837         800        -
Chase      8730923       250        Monthly
```

Is there an easy way of generating that Groups column in a sql query, that will combine the results of the join into a comma-separated field? I'm currently doing it on the php side using a secondary query on each row as I'm processing it. It's fine for a small dataset, but it seems pretty inefficient...

I'm using php > jet > ms access .mdb file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help [Does MS access(2003) have anything comparable to Stored procedure. I want to run a complex query in MS acceess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230241/does-ms-access2003-have-anything-comparable-to-stored-procedure-i-want-to-run)

Comment: I'm not sure how that gets to be counted as a correct answer, since VBA functions can't be executed via ODBC or OLEDB.