# Using MS Access VBA Function using Query in VB6

Tags: ms-access, vb6, ado, vba

I have defined a Function in MS Access database. I am using that function in Query. I saved that query as "Query1". This query runs successfully in MS Access. But, when I call the same query from VB (using ADO), it is giving me error:

```
Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)':

Undefined function 'Concatenate' in expression.
```

Below is the code I use to access "Query1":

```
rs.Open "Select * From Query1", CN1, 2, 2
If Not rs.EOF Then
'Get Data
End If
rs.Close
```

Comment: You haven't made clear whether your VB call is in Access still or another program, if still with Access then I suggest using DAO instead of ADO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use user defined functions (UDFs) outside of Access.

Comment: You can post the UDF if you want SO people to look at an alternative approach.

Comment: I am using Concatenate function to get comma separated string from one column of rows. Can this be done using normal ms access query?

Comment: @Chintan Shah No, you cannot concatenate without a UDF (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92698/combine-rows-in-access-2007/93863#93863, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230241/does-ms-access2003-have-anything-comparable-to-stored-procedure-i-want-to-run/231570#231570)