# Create stored procedure in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, stored-procedures

I would like to know if it's possible to create a `StoredProcedure` to `Insert` data in an Acces database. I've tried a couple of thing but nothing so far seem to do the trick.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a stored procedure in MS Access?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287545/how-do-i-make-a-stored-procedure-in-ms-access)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it is possible to create a `Stored Procedure` directly in access but it isn't pretty to do.

Your best options from here would be to :

- Simulate a `Stored Procedured` using a function. I found a  tutorial [here](http://dotnetnuke.adefwebserver.com/Default.aspx?tabid=167). But I haven't tried this approach.
- Another Popular approach seems to be to import an `SQLServer` `Stored Procedure` and Import it in Acess. Try [this](http://accessexperts.net/blog/2011/07/29/sql-server-stored-procedure-guide-for-microsoft-access-part-1/) link if you like this approach.
- If your using MS Access 2010, StoredProcedures will be listed in the tables tab under `Named Macros`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which version of MS Access.  Access 2010 has both stored procedures, and also has table triggers.

For access 2010, you open up the table (non design view), and then choose the table tab. You see options there to create store procedures and table triggers.

See the answer here:

[How do I make a stored procedure in MS Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287545/how-do-i-make-a-stored-procedure-in-ms-access)

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Access 2010 supports all sorts of cool stuff like stored procs and triggers.  (EDIT - See [@bluefeets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10144560/183624) answer for more on that).  However, if you're using anything less than 2010, you're going to have to write a [custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230241/does-ms-access2003-have-anything-comparable-to-stored-procedure-i-want-to-run) to get the results you're looking for.