# How can I create a stored procedure in MS Access 2013 like in MS SQL Server?

Tags: stored-procedures, ms-access-2013

So far, my own research shows two options:

1. [CREATE PROCEDURE statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845861.aspx): Close, but limited to a single SQL statement in execution.
2. [Create a Data Macro](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-data-macro-b1b94bca-4f17-47ad-a66d-f296ef834200): Which is more similar to "Triggers" in MS SQL Server.

Is there another way other than the ones listed above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on phadaphunk's answer **[here in another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10144587/2118383)**:

1. Simulate a stored procedure using a function. I found a tutorial [here](http://dotnetnuke.adefwebserver.com/Default.aspx?tabid=167). But I haven't tried this approach.
2. [How to use SQL Server Stored Procedures with Microsoft Access using Pass Through Queries](http://accessexperts.net/blog/2011/07/29/sql-server-stored-procedure-guide-for-microsoft-access-part-1/).
3. If you are using MS Access 2010 or above, stored procedures will be listed in the tables tab under [`Named Macros`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-data-macro-b1b94bca-4f17-47ad-a66d-f296ef834200).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Accepted because it contains two additional approaches which I have not considered.

Comment: The second option, *"import a SQL Server stored procedure into Access"*, is misleading. The linked article talks about *executing* SQL Server stored procedures from Access. Those stored procedures will run on the SQL Server and will only be able to manipulate resources that the SQL Server can "see". There is no way to "import" a (T-SQL) stored procedure into Access and have it run in Access itself.